# Escaping special characters

Tags: php, javascript

Just a quick question. I want to send data from Javascript to a PHP script to store it in my database, then getting it back the same way (a script calls a PHP function, and data is sent back with JSON).

Which function should I use in the javascript ? I should never need to get the data only with PHP, so is it ok to use `escape(string);` then `unescape(encoded_string);` to display ?

Thanks.
Regards from France ;)

EDIT : Forgot to mention : The data is a string from an user input (hence the security issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent()` for transmission in a url.

```
function sendData(str)
{
  var url = "http://myserver.com/upload?data="+encodeURIComponent(str);
  ajax(url);
}
```

When the data gets sent to the server, the server should automatically unencode the data that was sent in the URL, so you don't need to do it manually. (I'm not too familiar with PHP, though, someone correct me if I'm wrong.) You also don't need to encode data that is sent to the client, because it isn't being sent in a URL.

Just a word of caution:

If you `escape()` the data, and then `unescape()` it later, all html tags, javascript and other things the user entered will be restored exactly as they were. So be sure to remove those things before displaying the data.

See also: http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Comment: The thing is, i'm sending the data using jQuery's $.getJSON() function, giving him a map of the pramaeters, including the message's body. So the `encodeURIComponent()` isn't enough, because nothing is done to the quotes, only to special characters like é,è,à,$,#,!,?,...

Comment: @Squ36 `encodeURIComponent()` encodes everything except for ~!*()', but JSON normally uses double quotes (") anyway, so that shouldn't be a problem. Also, I don't think any of those characters have a special meaning in URLs, so you shouldn't need to replace them.